# Why do I get the error message : Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "text: function (){return $data.tracks.items[0].id }"...?

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I'm getting the following error: Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "text: function (){return $data.tracks.items[0].id }" Message: Cannot read property 'items' of undefined.

Basically, what I'm doing is bringing info this API provides https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/console/get-search-item/ and showing it accordginly.

I have checked whether I'm addressing the JSON wrong, but I think I'm not.

This is my html file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Spotify</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/design.css"/>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h1>Spotify</h1>
        <form data-bind="submit: guardar"> 
            <div>
                <label> Name (of the artist, track or album): </label><input type="text" id ='query' data-bind="value: query">
                <p>
                    <select id = "itemType">
                        <option value="" >Choose item type...</option>
                        <option value="artist">Artist</option> 
                        <option value="track">Track</option>
                        <option value="album">Album</option>
                    </select></p>
            </div>
            <button type="submit">Search</button> 
        </form>      

        <table id="artist" class="drop-down-show-hide">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Popularity</th>
                    <th>URI</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody data-bind= "foreach: queries">
                <tr>
                    <td data-bind="text: $data.artists.items[0].name"></td>
                    <td data-bind="text: $data.artists.items[0].popularity"></td>
                    <td data-bind="text: $data.artists.items[0].uri"></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <table id="track" class="drop-down-show-hide">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Artist</th>
                    <th>Album Type</th>
                    <th>URI</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody data-bind= "foreach: queries">
                <tr>
                    <td data-bind="text: $data.tracks.items[0].artists[1].name"></td>
                    <td data-bind="text: $data.tracks.items[0].album.album_type"></td>
                    <td data-bind="text: $data.tracks.items[0].uri"></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>       -->

        <table id="album" class="drop-down-show-hide">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>URL to listen on Spotify</th>
                    <th>URI</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody data-bind= "foreach: queries">
                <tr>
                    <td data-bind="text: $data.albums.items[0].external_urls.spotify"></td>
                    <td data-bind="text: $data.albums.items[0].uri"></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>


        </table>
    </div>
    <script src="libs/jquery-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/knockout-3.4.0.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

This is my js file:

```
(function ($, ko) {
var vm = {
    query: ko.observable('Muse'),
    itemType: ko.observable('Artist'),
    queries: ko.observableArray([]),
    guardar: function () {
        q = document.getElementById("query").value;
        it = document.getElementById("itemType").value;
        if (q !== "" && it !== "") {
            $.getJSON('https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=' + q + '&type=' +
                    it ).done(function (response) {
                vm.queries(response);
                this;
            });
        } else {
            alert("Llene todos los campos, por favor.");
        }
    }
    };
    ko.applyBindings(vm);

})(jQuery, ko);

$('.drop-down-show-hide').hide();

$('#itemType').change(function(){
    $(this).find("option").each(function(){
        $("#" + $(this).val()).hide();
        console.log($(this));
    });    
    $("#" + $(this).val()).show();
});
```

Thank youuuuu!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Couple of things**

1. **Replace** - You declare `vm.queries` as an array but **replace** it with Spotify's response, which is a *single* object of either artists, tracks, or albums.

Solution: Replace `<tbody data-bind="queries">` with `<tbody data-bind="items">`

`items` is an array that will be in the right context (see below)

2. **Context** - Items is undefined because `queries` contains **either** artists, tracks, or albums. Therefore $data.queries.*albums* will be absent when *artists* is requested.

Solution: Guard the table bindings using `data-bind="with: queries().albums"`

3. **Simplify** - Now that the table bindings are in the right context, simplify the table rows to

Example: tracks

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: items">
  <tr>
    <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: popularity"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: uri"></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Here's a [working demo](https://jsbin.com/jilotawika/edit?html,js,output).

Other things you can (optionally) consider are:

- Binding the select drop down to itemType
- Replacing the jQuery change event handler to subscribe to that drop down
- Using ko.components for the tables

Comment: Thaaaank you so much! :D :D